# Data mismatch during time conversion

Tags: node-red

I try to convert the time to STRING in nodered and I always get the result one hour higher. How do I do it right?

[image]
[image]

Thanks for helping with this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node-RED uses the timezone of the OS it's running on (not the browser you access it with).

You can use the `TZ` environment variable to set the active timezone before starting Node-RED and it will run in the timezone you want.

e.g.

```
export TZ=Europe/Paris
```

Also it's important to notice that the input times are in UTC (as denoted by the `Z` on the end so are being converted to BST which is why there is an hours difference.

Comment: Thank you, it works correctly, I misinterpreted these times.